# U-Net doesn't work with images different from the dataset

Tags: python, cnn, image-segmentation, image

I have implemented a very similar U-Net code from [github](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/076-077-078-Unet_nuclei_tutorial.py), but for a different dataset, [this one](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/data/), to segment roads, it works fine using the test folder images, but when i for example, pick a print from bing maps and try to infer with the trained model, this is returned:

[image]

Why this is happening?

Already tried change the thresholding values, normalization and etc.

[Tensorboard](https://tensorboard.dev/experiment/voY25RDaQ4yKSEDWrlhqEg/)

Comment: Are you applying the same preprocessing that was used when training the model to new image? In addition, to the input images look similar?

Comment: Yes, i think that they are very similar, as you can see here https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/data/mass_roads/train/sat/index.html , and compare with the one in the post.